# How to attach docs to email ActiveStorage and Cloudinary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary, rails-activestorage

I'm using ActiveStorage with Cloudinary:

```
gem 'cloudinary', '~> 1.14.0'
gem 'activestorage-cloudinary-service', '~> 0.2.3'
```

I have the following on my mailer:

```
if @job_request.work_files.attached?
  @job_request.work_files.each do |file|
    attachments[file.blob[:filename]] = { mime_type: file.blob.content_type, content: file.download }
  end
end
```

This raises an error on Heroku:

```
SendGridActionMailer::DeliveryMethod::SendgridDeliveryError

Sendgrid delivery failed with 400 The attachment content is required.
```

Users can submit job requests with files (using ActiveStorage and Cloudinary, Cloudinary allows to submit images, docs, pdf, and spreadsheets).
I need to attach those files to the email and send it, what could be the fix?

Answer (score 1):

I simply used the `open-uri` library to open the remote file and attach it

```
require 'open-uri'

class MyMailer << ApplicationMailer
  def new_job(job_request)
     @job_request = job_request
     if @job_request.work_files.attached?
       @job_request.work_files.each do |file|
         temp_file = open(file.service_url).read
         attachments[file.blob[:filename]] = { mime_type: file.blob.content_type, content: temp_file }
       end
     end

    mail to: @job_request.email
  end
end
```